# Unstable build file for angular.min.js should be used in my project or not?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the ng-if for showing the matched data from the json. Here, the current

```
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"
```

is not responding accordingly.
some where i found an example where they used another js file -

```
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js".
```

which when I replaced with. ng-if is working fine.

so, should I replace this file ? as they mentioned about this file is that "this is an unstable build".

what the unstable build means ? any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest stable version of angular JS is `1.2.21` - I'd recommend using that.  You can get the build from https://angularjs.org/.

Are you following some examples online? It's likely the examples are just outdated - Start off with `1.2.21` - The API docs for that build are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).  ([NG IF documentation is here)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 0):

RC -Release Candidate.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle):

> A release candidate (RC) is a beta version with potential to be a final product, which is ready to release unless significant bugs emerge. In this stage of product stabilization, all product features have been designed, coded and tested through one or more beta cycles with no known showstopper-class bug. A release is called code complete when the development team agrees that no entirely new source code will be added to this release. There could still be source code changes to fix defects, changes to documentation and data files, and peripheral code for test cases or utilities. Beta testers, if privately selected, will often be credited for using the release candidate as though it were a finished product. Beta testing is conducted in a client's or customer's location and to test the software from a user's perspective.

You can find all stable versions **[HERE](https://code.angularjs.org/)** or **[HERE](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#angularjs)**.

It seems like [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) comming with version 1.1.*